# How to move UIAWrapper windows in pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I noticed there's a method for moving and resizing win32 windows through the HwndWrapper in pywinauto (move_window), but nothing of the sort for UIAWrappers. Do you know how this could be done?

I've tried using pygetwindow's `getWindowsWithTitle` function to get a temporary win32 handle and then using the moveTo/resizeTo functions, but I can't get the window I want because of an error saying `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected WinFunctionType instance instead of WinFunctionType`, which is really weird.

Comment: you code must be in code block thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! This is not implemented in "uia" backend the same way as for "win32" backend. But I can suggest working code:

```
import pywinauto

app = pywinauto.Application(backend='uia').start(r'.\apps\WPF_samples\WpfApplication1.exe')
main = app.WPFSampleApplication.wrapper_object()

main.iface_transform.Move(0, 0) # move the window to top-left corner
main.iface_transform.Resize(500, 600) # change width and height
```

We need to provide shortcut methods and create `WindowWrapper` since this is specific for this control type only. This is tracked in the [issue #668](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/668).

Comment: If it resolves your problem, please mark this answer as accepted (gray check box at the left side of the answer). It will indicate the question green for others in the tag "pywinauto" feed. Reputation doesn't affect this check box. You're always able to do it, even for your own answer.

Comment: Oh okay, I just did that. Sorry I'm relatively new here